# Update user's last sign in time when logging in again

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

for example:
if the user login at 10:45 AM and logs out and then when he login's again the value of last_sign_in should be 10:45 AM and current_sign_in value should be current Time.

```
def method_name  
 old_current, new_current = self.current_sign_in_at, Time.now.utc  
 self.last_sign_in_at     = old_current || new_current  
 self.current_sign_in_at  = new_current   
end
```

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Comment: Doesn't devise store it automatically?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh no it is not storing.It is storing only one value 12:00 AM.

Comment: @ChristianWill please do see now..help me please if you know how to do it

Comment: What is your question in the first place?

Comment: i want to update last_sign_in_at and current_sign_in_at but it is not updating how can i do that?@mudasobwa

Comment: Do you have devise Trackable for your user model?

Comment: Trackable.rb?@Manishh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method looks fine, though it's not currently saving the attributes.

Assuming this method is in `user.rb`, you just need to add:

```
def method_name  
  old_current, new_current = current_sign_in_at, Time.now.utc  
  self.last_sign_in_at     = old_current || new_current  
  self.current_sign_in_at  = new_current   
  save
end
```

You could also look at using [update_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) or similar.

It sounds like you'll just need to call this method on the user in the relevant controller action. If you post a little more code, I can tailor this, though hopefully that'll get you in the right direction.